# Print LONG_MIN in C

Tags: c

How I can print LONG_MIN *-9223372036854775808* ? (LONG_MAX is working)

```
#include <unistd.h>

int     ft_putchar(int c)
{
    return (write(1, &c, 1));
}

void    ft_putlnbr(long int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        n = -n;
    }
    if (n >= 10)
        ft_putlnbr(n / 10);
    ft_putchar((n % 10) + '0');
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Don't use `n = -n` for negative numbers for the `LONG_MIN` case. You can use `/` and `%` on negative numbers.

Comment: @Franck Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @dai `-LONG_MIN` is signed integer overflow which is undefined behavior in C.  Best to avoid.

Comment: @t4Planeur The coding of `LONG_MIN` is usually `0x8000000000000000` on 64-bits machine with a bit sign = 1. The opposite operation takes the two's complement (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). On `LONG_MIN`, such a result would give `0x8000000000000000`. As it is still negative, the `C` standard defines this case as undefined behavior. Note that `LONG_MIN = -LONG_MAX-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embrace the dark side (use the negative side of the `long` range).

A simple recursive C99/C11 solution:

```
static void print_long_helper(long n) {
  if (n <= -10) {
    print_long_helper(n / 10);
  }
  putchar('0' - n % 10);
}

void print_long(long n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    putchar('-');
  } else {
    n = -n;  // Make positive numbers, negative - no chance for overflow
  }
  print_long_helper(n);
  puts("");
}

int main() {
  print_long(0);
  print_long(1);
  print_long(-1);
  print_long(INT_MAX);
  print_long(INT_MIN);
  return 0;
}
```

Output on my 32-bit `long` machine

```
0
1
-1
2147483647
-2147483648
```

Comment: @t4Planeur Be sure to UV all useful answers, not just the selected one,

Comment: You might want to add `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN` to your test function, it is after all the purpose of the question ;-)

Comment: Elegant approach indeed.

Comment: Hmmm, Thought I had used `LONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve this, but first you must fix your character writing function: the address of the `int` argument is not necessarily the same as that of the low order byte. Your function is not portable.  Use this instead:

```
int ft_putchar(char c) {
    return write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

You can use an unsigned long variable:

```
void ft_putlnbr(long int n) {
    unsigned long u = n;
    if (n < 0) {
        ft_putchar('-');
        u = -u;
    }
    if (u >= 10) {
        ft_putlnbr(u / 10);
    }
    ft_putchar(u % 10 + '0');
}
```

You can operate on the negative value and use a loop and a buffer:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ft_putlnbr(long int n) {
    char buf[(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type)/3 + 3)];
    size_t i = sizeof(buf);

    if (n < 0) {
        while (n <= -10) {
            buf[--i] = '0' - n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        buf[--i] = '0' - n;
        buf[--i] = '-';
    } else {
        while (n >= 10) {
            buf[--i] = '0' + n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        buf[--i] = '0' + n;
    }
    while (i < sizeof(buf)) {
        ft_putchar(buf[i++]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ft_putlnbr()` is a very reasonable and highly portable approach.  The only weakness is the corner of C which allows something like `9,223,372,036,854,775,808 == LONG_MAX == ULONG_MAX` which likely applies to 3 computers rusting away in some silicon graveyard.

Comment: Thank you but @chux given a better solution

Comment: @chux: you are correct, and I posted the second solution for complete portability (except you would need to compute the buffer size from `sizeof(long)` and `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: Nice.  A slightly inefficient buffer size of an integer type is `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type)/3 + 3)`.

Comment: @chux: yes, this expression even works on the DS9K-64 you were referring to in your comment ;-)